# Why Design(activity_main.xml) and actual app look different?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity

i am new in Android development in java

my activity_main.xml file is look like this
[image: activity_main.xml design]

But when i run this application in my pixel 3 phone than it's look's like[image: pixel 3 phone]

why this design are different ?

Comment: Can you provide your activity_main.xml code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen in background, you ignore missing constraints. When working with ConstraintLayout you must provide at least one horizontal and one vertical constraint, otherwise views could jump, and I believe IDE gave u that error.

Answer (score 0):

check your style file.
By default is with Dialog.
u can change it with No Dialog

Sorry i mean
the line

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

u can change the theme with no actionbar

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

there are many variants

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have a full screen theme like  Design(activity_main.xml):

**solution 1**: go into the manifest and use a full screen theme.

```
 <activity
   . 
   .
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```

**solution 2**:

Just add the following attribute to your current theme:

```
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

for example :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/orange</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/holo_orange_dark</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

**solution 3** :

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
```

}

and for manage your buttons, read **Dorian's answer** to Design and actual app look same.